# Sentence formation

Tags: prepositions

While working on an exercise on using prepositions, I came across a sentence:

`Dad went _____ (at/from/to) outside to see what the noise was about.`

Here I am not sure if `Dad went to outside...` is grammatically correct.

Could you provide your suggestions?

Comment: All of these prepositions are incorrect. No preposition is used in the idiomatic phrases _go out(side)/go in(side)/go home_.

Comment: @John Lawler if you could kindly make that as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use any preposition at all.

Simply say:

> Dad went outside to see what the noise was about.

There are some more complex constructions—when talking about going from the inside to the outside, for instance—where a preposition could be used, but those don't apply to this simple sentence.